# Desperately searching an multiple image picker from phone gallery in flutter - for iOS

Tags: flutter, plugins, imagepicker

I'm desperately seeking for an `multiple image picker with (videos inclusive)`  plugin in flutter, especially for iOS devices.

Does anyone have recommendation?
I tried already:

```
multiple_image_picker 0.4.8 
file_picker:...
multi_image_picker:...
photo_manager:...
```

Non of them satisfied me.

The best would be sth. like the ``ìmage_picker:``` -> https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker <-

but with video upload capability and multiple selection.

Please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this one:

https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker

It is referred to from the multi_image_picker's discontinued information.

Comment: just loaded the example and tested it quickly... it's what i need :)

thanks @Robert Sandberg